# How to check Regular Expression in particular function or class?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to make a regular expression that checks for the Camel Casing for the name of variables.

The expression I have got so far is:

```
(?xm-isn:(?:\b\w*(?:-)\w*\s*\=)|(?:\b[A-Z0-9_-]+(?=\s*\W*\b)\s*\=))
```

which works fine.

The question is, how can I make an exception for the following part of the code so it doesn't consider this naming convention for that particular part of the code in the file?

```
public enum ProjectType
{
    [DisplayName("All")]
    All = 0,

    [DisplayName("All .NET - Windows Forms and Web Forms")]
    AllNet = 1,
}
```

Comment: Where did you get this regex? It doesn't really make a lot of sense, and it's not working either. What exactly do you want it to do? What should it match, and how can it tell when it should not match?

Comment: Hi Tim,

I have got this regex from the tool "Expresso" and it works fine for camel casing.
So if it matches the string it displays it in Search Result of Expresso
But when I run with the code block of enum it also detects those variable inside it which I don't want to be detected and need them to be an exception.
I just wanted it to be out of enum {} block which I could not find it out.
It matches variable names which are nor in Camel Casing 
x. MyVarOne, _VarOne like that. 

So far I could make this  (?xm-isn:(?!enum\s+\w+\s*\{\w*+\s*\}       ()    )
and in the parenthesis at last

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to check Regular Expression in particular function of class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173917/how-to-check-regular-expression-in-particular-function-of-class).  Please don't post the same question multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is great for pattern matching but not lexical analysis. I suggest you look into that by using such tools as [Garden Points Lexical Analysis](http://Gardens%20Point%20LEX).