# How to check Regular Expression in particular function of class?

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to make a regular expression that checks for the Camel Casing for the name of variables.

The expression I have got so far (which works fine) is:

```
(?xm-isn:(?:\b\w*(?:-)\w*\s*\=)|(?:\b[A-Z0-9_-]+(?=\s*\W*\b)\s*\=))
```

However, how can I make an exception for the following part of the code so it doesn't consider this naming convention for that particular part of the code in the file?

```
public enum ProjectType
{
    [DisplayName("All")]
    All = 0,
    [DisplayName("All .NET - Windows Forms and Web Forms")]
    AllNet = 1,
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You could use FxCop and [create your own rule to perform this check](http://www.thescarms.com/dotnet/FxCop1.aspx).

Comment: +1. As @Tim commented in the other copy of this question, that regex makes no sense at all.  You'll be much better off using a purpose-made tool for this.